# Data passing in Swift UITableViewController Initializer

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I am facing a weird problem. I have a Custom class `FormDataSource` like below

```
class FormDataSource{

var Sections: Array<SectionDataProvider>?;
var Rows:Array<Array<RowDataProvider>>!;
var formData: Dictionary<String, Any?>!;

init(sections:Array<SectionDataProvider>?, withRows:Array<Array<RowDataProvider>>){
    self.Sections = sections;
    self.formData = [String:Any?]();
    self.Rows = withRows;

    for rowArray in self.Rows
    {
        for row in rowArray
        {
            self.formData.updateValue(row.actualData, forKey: row.keyForRowData);
        }
    }
}
}
```

And a `UITableViewController` subclass `FormViewController` like below

```
class FormViewController:UITableViewController{

var formDataSource:FormDataSource!;

init(with  DataSource :FormDataSource) {

    self.formDataSource = DataSource;

    println("count: \(self.formDataSource.Rows.count)"); //prints 3 correctly
    super.init(style: UITableViewStyle.Plain);
}

override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {

    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil);
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder);
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad();

    println("count: \(self.formDataSource.Rows.count)"); //crash at this line

}
}
```

when I am creating a new instance of the `FormViewController` It crashes inside `viewDidLoad` giving

`"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"`.

The code is given below:

```
var dataSource = FormDataSource(sections: nil, withRows:rows);

    let joinView:FormViewController = FormViewController(with: dataSource);
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(joinView, animated: true);
```

I guess the cause might be that the variable I am passing is being destroyed. Can anyone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you built your TableViewController with InterfaceBuilder then either

```
init(coder)
```

or

```
init(nibName)
```

is called for initialization. 
That means that your `formData` property is not being initalized and it results in that error.

Set breakpoints in the various init functions to see which one gets called.

Comment: I haven't created the TableViewController in IB. The `init` function is called fine and the `println` inside that is executed and prints the correct value, so the `self.formDataSource` inside `init` is not null at that point but the `println` inside `viewDidLoad` crashes due to the `self.formDataSource` being nil